# Average behavior of degree distribution plots

Tags: list-manipulation, graphs-and-networks, distributions, averages

I'll show what I'm doing in the moment and after that I'll explain what I'm trying to achieve. I use the following code to generate a large number of Barabási-Albert networks, and after that I plot the degree distribution of these networks.

```
net = Table[BarabasiAlbertGraphDistribution[100, 2], 5];
graph = RandomGraph /@ net;
degree = VertexDegree /@ graph;
k = Union /@ degree;
prob = Table[ (Table[
  Probability[x >= i, x \[Distributed] deg[[j]]], {i, #}] &@
k[[j]]), {j, 1, Length[k]}];
cdf = Table[Transpose@{k[[i]], prat[[i]]}, {i, 1, Length[prat]}];
ListLogLogPlot[Table[cdf[[i]], {i, 1, 5}]]
```

From the ListLogLogPlot command I get the following plot:
[image: Degree distribution of the Barabas-Albert graphs]

Each color represent a dataset from the code above. Since the graphs generated through the Barabasi model are random, I generate a large number of them in order to find the average behavior of the degree distribution in order to compare it with the degree distribution of other network models. However, I can't find a function that works in this kind of datasets, specially because they have different lengths when you are working with large networks (4000-10000 nodes).

I tried using the Flatten and Union functions in order to have only one list with data points and used LinearFit and Interpolation functions without success. After Flatten and Union I have a plot like this:

```
b = Union[Flatten[cdf,1]]
ListLogLogPlot[b]
```

[image]

But even with a list with only one dataset the FitLinear and Interpolation functions won't work.
Does anyone have a clue if I can find the average representation of these kind of datasets with Mathematica?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are working with distributions. Instead of averaging, simply combine the data from multiple graphs before visualizing the distribution.

This combines the degrees from 1000 graphs:

```
degs = Join @@ 
   VertexDegree /@ 
    RandomGraph[BarabasiAlbertGraphDistribution[100, 2], 1000];
```

Visualizing the "CDF from the right" (survival function) only requires reverse sorting the data.

```
ListLogLogPlot[
 Transpose@{ReverseSort[degs], Range@Length[degs]}
 ]
```

[image]

Or use [`Histogram`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Histogram.html)

```
Histogram[degs, {"Log", Automatic}, {"Log", "PDF"}]
```

[image]

```
Histogram[degs, {"Log", Automatic}, {"Log", "SurvivalCount"}]
```

[image]

Combining the data first and then histogramming is in fact equivalent to histogramming first and then averaging histograms. Thus, don't try to average. Just combine the data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I tried working on the full degree distribution of a huge number of networks but my problem was that I was treating it like an average, not a distribution like you showed. Thanks!